# jQuery Get Class That Starts With A String

Tags: jquery, class, startswith

The selector class can be:

```
c-1
c-2
c-3
(etc...)
```

The selector can also have other classes, so here is an example of a possible HTML:

```
<div class="foo c-2 foofoo"></div>
```

I want to get the number after the `c`. In this case - I'll get `2`.

How can I do that?

Comment: Can you accept the answer that worked for you @Ariel?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Try

```
var el = $('.c-2')//get the element whose class value has to be extracted
var val = el.attr('class').match(/\bc-(\d+)\b/)[1]
```

Comment: this is really amazing!

Answer (score 1):

If you sure that no other integers present in your class

try

```
var s ="foo c-2 foofoo";
var result = /\d+(?:\.\d+)?/.exec(s);
alert(result);  //2 is the result
```

[**Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/fRUUd/1555/)